# Dropdown in Magento Frontpage displaying all products

Tags: php, javascript, magento, drop-down-menu, product

I have a Magento website selling magazine subscriptions, about a 1000 different titels. What I would like is to create a very simple dropdown menu prefilled with **all** products on the frontpage. Very much like [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/navigation/add_dropdown_list_of_manufactures_or_another_attribute), only I cannot seem to replace the 'manufactures' with 'name' (the product name).

An example can be found [here](http://www.123tijdschrift.nl/) with a different website selling magazine subscriptions as well (right top, left to the search field).

Can someone present we with some code to create such a dropdownlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the other website you linked to, the drop down HTML looks like this, with a small snippet of JavaScript inside `onselect` attribute to navigate to the URL of the selected product:

```
<select ... onchange="window.location.href = this.value">
  <option>Select a product</option>
  <option value="/path-to-foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="/path-to-bar">Bar</option>
</select>
```

The JavaScript navigates by setting `window.location.href` to a new URL, and it gets this URL from `this.value` which is the value of the selected `<option>`.

To render a drop down like this in Magento you first have to get all products using [Mike Bywaters' code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8530252/4830) (filtered by visible and whatnot). Then you loop through all the products and you `echo` the `<option>` tag for each product with the correct value:

```
echo "<option value=\"/" . $product->getUrlPath() . "\">";
echo $product->getName();
echo "</option>";
```

If `$product` is the result of a call to `Mage::getModel(...)` then a call to `$product->getUrlPath()` should return the path of the product, [as documented here](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product.html#getUrlPath).

Comment: Thanks! this works like a charm. Only thing left is I would like to arrange all titles (products) in alphabetical order. Now they are arranged in order of their ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the template file where you want the drop down:

```
<select>
    <?php
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => '1'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'));
        foreach ($products as $prod_model) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod_model->getId());
            echo "<option value=\"".$product->getId()."\">".$product->getName()."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

It will only get active simple products, but you can add additional filters depending on product attribute values with the ->addAttributeToFilter() function.

EDIT: Also, it will take a long time to process if you have a lot of products, and especially long if you don't have caching enabled. This isn't really recommended.

Comment: Thanks! .... but you are right, it takes far to long to load them all. 

But when turning caching on, it seems to work rather well. 

A couple of things remain:

1. it will show non-visible products as well. I added, but didn't do the job:

->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('eq' => 'Catalog, search'))

2. when selecting a product it, will not direct you to it. (it just shows the names now)
3. how to put a first selection with text, like 'select a title'.

Comment: @Mike, I recommend you look at the source to [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer#prepareProductCollection()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer.html#prepareProductCollection) which is responsible for the 'normal' feel of product lists such as this little gem, `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);`

Comment: off the top of my head, "visibility" can be set to 0, 1, 2 or 3. If you want that drop down to do something, you'll need to attach JavaScript of some sort to it. If you want to put a blank option, add <option>please select</option> after the first select tag, before the PHP

Comment: Thanks clockwork geek, that looks handy. I haven't really delved too far into the Magento catalog, so I'll have a look over catalog/layer when I hit the office on Monday. Cheers

Comment: Hi again! Happy new year to you all. The visibility set works great for me. Could someone help me with the last detail, the JavaScript  part where I can actually direct people to the productpage when choosing one (and adding a top selecting with text "Select product"